# How to install python to /usr/bin instead of /usr/local/bin

Tags: software-installation, python

I have a python library which needs 2.7.10 version for it to function. But, When I download the python binaries and install, it is being installed in the /usr/local/bin folder. When I run the python executable in the local/bin folder, it doesn't have the set of libraries which I installed previously. After some debugging found out that the libraries were installed in the /usr/bin folder.

Is there a way to upgrade the python associated with /usr/bin folder?

Comment: Why are you installing your own Python 2? Does the library not work with the Python 2 that ships with Ubuntu?

Comment: @edwinksl The version of the default python was 2.7.6. The library wants version 2.7.10

Comment: Usually a requirement will be greater than or equal to. Version 2.7.11 is available on a newer version. It would not be difficult to set up apt preferences to only pull the needed packages from the newer repository. If 2.7.11 is sufficient, let me know and I'll try and come up with a working answer for you.

Comment: Can you please be specific about the libs because another solution may be just to link the libs to /usr/local/bin, thanks.

Comment: I believe that the library version will install in usr/local/bin and then have a symlink in usr/bin.